# How to run multiple task in Telebot Python

Tags: python, telebot

I am currently using `AsyncTelebot` for Telegram bot. But I want to switch to Telebot. Because I need to use `await` function constantly in AsyncTelebot. But also `async.gather()` works for me for multitasking. In Telebot the `asyncio.gather()` function runs only one task.

Codes:

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.Telebot(token)

def task():
  data = ""
  while True:
      for i in list(db.find()):
          data += f"""{i["id"]: {i["data"]}\n"""
      if data != "":
          bot.send_message(log_id, data)
          break


# Only "bot.polling()" works in Telebot. Both work in AsyncTelebot.

def main():
  print("working..")
  asyncio.gather(bot.polling(), task())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

In summary, I want to run two tasks simultaneously in Telebot.

Answer (score 0):

use threading:

```
import telebot
from threading import Thread

bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)


def task1():
    #Code

def task2():
    #Code


if __name__ == "__main__":
  Thread(target=lambda: bot.infinity_polling()).start()
  Thread(target=lambda: task1()).start()
  Thread(target=lambda: task2()).start()
```